# Microsoft Driver for PHP is not working with Sql Server 2012 express

Tags: php, sql-server

I have windows 10 machine (64 bit), with PHP (v=7.1.2) and Apache.
I have installed Sql Server 2012 (64 bit) and Microsoft PHP driver (version 4) from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098

I have all the driver dll in my php extension directory. I added the dll file in my php.ini file and restarted the Apache server

```
extension=php_sqlsrv_7_ts_x64.dll  
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_ts_x64.dll
```

But when I checked the phpinfo(), It was not present.
What could be the problem ?
Does sql server 2012 and PHP driver have problem with PHP 7 ?

*Note: MySQL is also present in my local server*

Comment: When the module does not show up in phpinfo(), it did simply not get loaded either due to wrong path or compatibility reason.

Comment: Look in Event Viewer > Windows Logs > Application

Comment: @AbraCadaver , Here is the log `PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:\PHP\ext\php_sqlsrv_7_ts_x64.dll' - The specified procedure could not be found. (C:\Apache24\bin\httpd.exe -d C:/Apache24)`

Answer (score 0):

I have searched lot and found that current PHP driver(4.0) is not compatible with PHP 7.1. 
There is a preview version released by Microsoft that is working. You can download it here  - https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql/releases/tag/v4.1.8-preview